# A very interesting problem.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Complete the following table of mathematical operations,
$$\begin{align*}2+2+2&=6\\ 3 \ \quad 3\ \quad 3&=6 \\ 4 \ \quad 4\ \quad 4&=6 \\ 5 \ \quad 5\ \quad 5&=6 \\ 6 \ \quad 6 \ \quad 6&=6 \\ 7 \ \quad 7\ \quad 7&=6 \\ 8 \ \quad 8\ \quad 8&=6 \\ 9 \ \quad 9\ \quad 9&=6\end{align*} $$

I know that in the second there is a $ \cdot $ and then a $ - $, and it is true that $ 3 \cdot 3-3 = 6 $, but in the others I do not know another complex mathematical operation that helps me complete that table, someone help me.

Comment: $5/5+5=6, 6+6-6=6 , 7-7/7=6$

Comment: All mathematical operations are legal.

Comment: I suggest frequent use of square roots and possibly factorials.

Comment: 3*3-3 = 6, sqrt(4)+sqrt(4)+sqrt(4) = 6, 7-7/7 = 6, 9 - 9 /sqrt(9) = 6

Comment: I define the mathematical operation $w$ which maps any ordered pair onto $6$.  $ 4 w 4 w 4 = 6 w 4 = 6$.  Done.  You're welcome.

Comment: Hmm, this reminds me of the "24 game" we played back in school, where you draw 4 random cards and try to make them = 24. Pretty fun! I wonder if there's a way to do 4, 8, and 9 without any roots though...

Comment: The title of this question is utterly useless for anyone wanting to search on MSE - and (IMHO) false.

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/funny/6by3digits.shtml uses the solution proposed by @BStar below in his comment for 8 (and adds (0! + 0! + 0!)! = (1! + 1! + 1!)! = 6)

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}2+2+2&=6\\ \sqrt 3 \cdot \sqrt 3\ +3&=6 \\ \sqrt4 +\sqrt 4\ +\sqrt 4&=6 \\ 5\div 5+ 5&=6 \\ 6 \cdot 6\div 6&=6 \\ -7\div{7}+7&=6 \\ \sqrt[3]8 +\sqrt[3]8 +\sqrt[3]8 &=6 \\ \sqrt 9 \cdot\sqrt 9\ -\sqrt 9&=6\end{align*} $$

Comment: cube root kinda seems like cheating imo

Comment: How about 8 – √(√(8 + 8)) = 6? We can argue  either way for this - it is square root of square root and fourth root at the same time:-).

Comment: The last line in your answer is not right. $\sqrt9 + \sqrt9 + \sqrt9$ is 9 not 6

Comment: @Alaleh Really - no one noticed till now:-).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$ 2 + 2 + 2 = 6 $$

$$ 3 \times 3 - 3 = 6 $$

$$ \sqrt4 +  \sqrt4 +  \sqrt4 = 6 $$

$$ 5\div5 + 5 = 6 $$

$$ 6 + 6 - 6 = 6 $$

$$ 7 - 7\div7 = 6$$

$$ \sqrt[3]8 + \sqrt[3]8  + \sqrt[3]8 = 6$$

$$ 9 - 9  \div \sqrt9 = 6 $$